# PHP export DBF file format

Tags: php, mysql

Do you have any idea on how to export a DBF file format using php without using the dbase function?

Comment: look like the user notes on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php is a good place to start

Comment: What is the reason behind not using dbase function

Comment: @Dagon, its export to dbf file format a dbase format file

Comment: @NaveenKumar, I cannot use dbase function because I cannot configure the apache

Comment: You dont have permission to configure apache or is it you don't know how to configure apache?

Comment: Actually i already configure it in my local by removing the comment in php.ini and restarted my apache and it works perpectly,but when I try to use it on my online we cannot make it work,so we decided not to use it,and use pure php code,actually I only want to know what should be the exact format of a dbf file in order to create the desired result.

Comment: Refer this link to know about the contents of DBF file format [DBF](http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dBase DBF file format is quite easy. Many years ago I had to import data from dbf/fpt (FoxPro), but I used standard PHP functions to read dbf files and just manually scanned the format of fpt files, where the long memo records were stored (dbf contained only pointers inside fpt).

You can check for example this description of dbf format: [dbf format](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm)

From there you can see that in the beginning there is a file header, which contains all information about the defined fields (field name, size, type and optionally any constraints). You will use PHP's `fwrite()` function to write the required binary data into the dbf files. After the header, dbf file contains individual records separated by space/asterisk. Individual fields inside a record are not separated, as each field has static length.

Comment: thanks in advance bro,do you have any sample there?I dont know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any sample, but you just need to follow the dbf format and `fwrite()` all fields into output file as specified in the format description.

Comment: in writing the data in the file using fwrite() what is the right format?because I can already write it to the file but when i open it there is no data,only column name appear